Scrollbar Goes Out of Bounds in Pygame_GUI Container
What I want is simple: a pygame_gui container that stores items and allows me to scroll through them without any issues. It seems like a straightforward requirement, so I’m puzzled as to why I can’t find a solution.
I am trying to add components inside a window or container, and I want a scrollbar to be generated when those components exceed the available vertical space. So far, everything seems to be set up correctly, but the scrollbar is not functioning as expected—it goes out of bounds when i reach the end of the container and appears quite buggy.
Can the library support something like this? I've tried everything.
import pygame
import pygame_gui

pygame.init()
window = pygame.display.set_mode((800, 600))
manager = pygame_gui.UIManager((800, 600))

container = pygame_gui.elements.UIScrollingContainer(
    relative_rect=pygame.Rect((50, 50), (300, 400)),
    manager=manager
)

for i in range(20):
    pygame_gui.elements.UILabel(
        relative_rect=pygame.Rect((0, i * 35), (280, 30)),
        text=f"Item {i+1}",
        manager=manager,
        container=container
    )

clock = pygame.time.Clock()
while True:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            exit()
        manager.process_events(event)

    manager.update(clock.tick(60)/1000.0)
    window.fill((128, 128, 128))
    manager.draw_ui(window)
    pygame.display.update()



thats because you havent set scrollable dimension to scrolling container so it appears buggy. You should explicity set its scrollable dimension plus, if horizontal scroll isnt needed disable it.
import pygame
import pygame_gui

pygame.init()
window = pygame.display.set_mode((800, 600))
manager = pygame_gui.UIManager((800, 600))

container = pygame_gui.elements.UIScrollingContainer(
    relative_rect=pygame.Rect((50, 50), (300, 400)),
    manager=manager,
    allow_scroll_x=False,
)
container.set_scrollable_area_dimensions(container.rect.size)

for i in range(20):
    pygame_gui.elements.UILabel(
        relative_rect=pygame.Rect((0, i * 35), (280, 30)),
        text=f"Item {i+1}",
        manager=manager,
        container=container
    )

clock = pygame.time.Clock()
while True:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            exit()
        manager.process_events(event)

    manager.update(clock.tick(60)/1000.0)
    window.fill((128, 128, 128))
    manager.draw_ui(window)
    pygame.display.update()

